# How to retrieve the eclipse launch location?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to access the eclipse.ini file . Since the location of the eclipse.ini would be same as the location of eclipse.exe , is there any way I could access this location through java code ?

Comment: Take a look at [ask].  What research have you done?

Comment: What is the current directory in your java code?

Comment: @MartinSerrano The only requirement I have is that I should not be providing the absolute path(hard code the path) to get access to the file . Since the location of the ini file is same as eclipse.exe , I want to know if there an api available to get the eclipse.exe location.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - The current directory would depend on the location of the java file which I am trying to run (location of workspace) . The location of the workspace can be different from the location of the eclipse.exe.

Comment: That is true....can I ask why you need to know the location?

Comment: @MiserableVariable - I need to access the max heap size that is set in the eclipse.ini .

Comment: This seems like something that would be exposed to plugins rather than the programs. I have no experience developing plugins, but [`org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FPlatform.html) seems interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Eclipse install directory location in a plugin with:

```
Location location = Platform.getInstallLocation();

URL locationURL = location.getURL();
```

The eclipse.ini should be in that directory.